# Implementing a custom hard sigmoid function

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow, activation-function

I need to implement an activation function that is similar to Keras's "hard-sigmoid", only for different limit values:

- 0 if x < 0
- 1 if x > 1
- x if 0 <= x <= 1

How do I implement it with a tensorflow backend Keras?

Comment: How about this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915482/how-do-you-create-a-custom-activation-function-with-keras
Then there you define your "hard-sigmoid" activation with desired boundaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411194/how-is-hard-sigmoid-defined) post, **hard-sigmoid** in Keras is implemented as 
`max(0, min(1, x*0.2 + 0.5))`. To obtain the graph you like you have to tweak the **shift** and **slope** parameters, i.e. leave them out in your case:

$$
max(0, min(1, x))
$$

This will generate following graph:

[image: hard-sigmoid]

For Keras' TensorFlow backend you can find the implementation [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L3596).
This would be the corresponding **changed "hard-sigmoid"**, for your case:

```
zero = _to_tensor(0., x.dtype.base_dtype)
one = _to_tensor(1., x.dtype.base_dtype)
x = tf.clip_by_value(x, zero, one)
return x
```